# Java (Swing) - Drag two windows at once

Tags: java, swing, drag

How can I have one window move with another?  i.e., I'd like a JDialog to follow a JFrame when the JFrame is being dragged.  If the JFrame moves by (+5, +20), the JDialog needs to move the same.

I've tried using ComponentListeners, but I only receive drag events in chunks which causes the JDialog window to be jumpy while dragging the main JFrame.  I've tried using MouseListeners, but I can't figure out how to detect events on the actual frame of the JFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK here is no move multiple windows in AWT. To get the moves to be called at a similar time, I guess you want the `JFrame` decorations to be PL&F rendered. Put in a PL&F-specific hack to do the moves yourself, moving both windows at almost the same time. You may still have a problem with exposing bits of windows only to cover them up causing some performance degradation.

Comment: Can you direct me to any specific classes for the PL&F that I can use to jump start this hack?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ComponentListener.componentMoved event instead of monitoring drag events on the JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

The component listener method works perfectly.
I did something like this:

```
Point p = this.getLocation();
p.x += this.getWidth() + 10;
this.getOwner().setLocation(p);
```

Where the '10' is the space between the current window(a JDialog) and its owner which is to its right.